# Conventional way of copying files in Gradle - use Copy task or copy method?

Tags: gradle

I'm adding a task to deploy war files to Tomcat .. the only thing that the task needs to do is copy the war file to the TOMCAT location.

There 2 ways that I can think of implementing this .. but being new to gradle, I'm not quite sure what's more conventional/right (or if it even matters).

```
task myCopy(type: Copy)

    myCopy.configure {
       from('source')
       into('target')
       include('*.war')
    }
```

or

```
task myCopy{
  doLast{
     copy {
       from 'source'
       into 'target'
       include '*.war'
     }   
  }

}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In most cases (including this one), the `Copy` task is the better choice. Among other things, it will give you automatic up-to-date checking. The `copy` method is meant for situations where (for some reason) you have to bolt on to an existing task and cannot use a separate task for copying.

The code for your `Copy` task can be simplified to:

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from('source')
    into('target')
    include('*.war')
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I understand the advantages of automatic up-to-date checking, what are the other advantages?

Comment: Better style (a task should do one thing and should be explicit about it), better configurability (e.g. from a parent build script and/or using a configuration rule).

Comment: For some reason this task doesn't run by default.

Answer (score 1):

UP-TO-DATE only verifies the file is in place but not if the files has changed
to avoid being cached with an old file use

```
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
```