# Copy task in gradle

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

I am trying to do a simple file copy from one folder into another using gradle.

```
task copyTask(type: Copy) {

    from 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    into 'libs/x86'

}
```

This works, but

```
task copyTask(type: Copy) {

    from 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    into 'libs'

}
```

This doesn't. Neither does this :

```
task copyTask(type: Copy) {

    from 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    into '../val'

}
```

I tried substituting with absolute paths but that didn't work either.
I checked a few examples on [working with files](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) and the relative path structure that i am using seems to be ok.

Why does only one relative path format work? 
Also if I try copying *.jar files instead of AndroidManifest.xml, that does not work either. What is wrong with my copy task?

Comment: Can you provide the error that you get? I tried to repro your examples but for me it worked as expected.

Comment: It does not throw any error, says Build successful, but when i look at the folder no files have been copied. I am using the command gradle copyTask.

Comment: Can you try running gradle with --info flag? This should provide you useful information about the execution of your task, e.g. where these files were copied to

Comment: Why are you trying to copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` in your libs? `x86` may not be available if you ran `gradlew clean` before hand.

Comment: @Jared, just as a test. I am actually trying to copy *.jar files, but that's not working. The .xml file is being copied over in at least one scenario. I did not run clean before.

Comment: @user1411110 Can you try my answer?

Comment: @Jared, yes i tried running with the --info switch and I see that the task gets skipped because it is up to date. I am trying to see if I can force it to check the output update every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002455/950427):

This does what you want but copies `*.wars`.

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from('source')   // <-- folder
    into('target')   // <-- folder
    include('*.war') // <-- file(s)
}
```

You said in the comments you wanted to copy `*.jars`:

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from('source')   // <-- folder
    into('target')   // <-- folder
    include('*.jar') // <-- file(s)
}
```